# How make a window with the password between Views?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I'm using a storyboard with two Views. ("PasswordViewController" and "DestinationViewController")

In PasswordViewController I have a "Password" field and "OK" button.

Question: I cannot to set the "Segue" correctly from "OK" button to the "DestinationViewController". It must be opened only after the specific password, typed in the "Password" field otherwise it should n't do anything. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are easy. Here is the code for Duncan's suggestion.

```
 - (IBAction)okButton:(id)sender
    {    
        if (passwordTextfield.text > spaces) //or whatever condition you would like to put
        {
           UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

           //You need to set below identifier (PasswordView) through your storyboard.
           PasswordViewController *passwordViewController = 
              [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PasswordView"]; 

          [self.navigationController pushViewController:passwordViewController animated:YES];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in the `PasswordViewController` to return `YES` if the password verification has been successful, and `NO` otherwise.

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"open DestinationViewController"]) {
        return [self checkPassword]; // checkPassword method returns YES when the password is right
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @user922907 Did you try any of the solutions? Did it work, or are you continue seeing problems?

Comment: @user922907 The problem with the accepted solution is that it entirely ignores your segue, replacing it with code in the button's handler.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to control-drag a segue from the view controller's content view to the other view controller (instead of from the button.) Set an identifier for the segue, and then write a button IBAction method that invokes performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: if the password is valid, and does not open the destination view controller if the password is invalid.